# Using libpqxx and C++ - how to instantiate a connectionObject and an worker in a different class

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpq, libpqxx

Here's the example function:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

int main()
{
    std::string connectionString = "host=ec2-54-74-35-87.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=d8iolcesns1bj4 user=pktunepcutgdqh password=7e3eeef2e01e0d8ae555c7236b1c3375789259dfb6acba41225cc4f55394836c";

    try
    {
        pqxx::connection connectionObject(connectionString.c_str());

        pqxx::work worker(connectionObject);

        pqxx::result response = worker.exec("SELECT * FROM Users");

        for (size_t i = 0; i < response.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << "Id: " << response[i][0] << " Username: " << response[i][1] << " Password: " << response[i][2] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

And I would like to create a class which would hold the data about the connection, like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

class DBLink
{
    std::string connectionString = "host=ec2-54-74-35-87.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=d8iolcesns1bj4 user=pktunepcutgdqh password=7e3eeef2e01e0d8ae555c7236b1c3375789259dfb6acba41225cc4f55394836c";
    pqxx::connection connectionObject(connectionString.c_str());
    pqxx::work worker(connectionObject);
};
```

but for some reason I get some errors:
[image: photo]

is there any way to fix them?

Comment: You placed statements in the class, but the class expects members. Remove statements, define members and define the class constructor. Any good C++ book will help you.

Comment: @S.M. would you mind showing me an example, please?

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: I did it, it worked, nevermind. Write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it asap :)

Comment: Glad to see you did it. My comment is not worth to be an answer.

Comment: You have a chance to answer and get points here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875116/making-worker-a-static-parameter-libpqxx

Comment: @S.M. I would if I knew :) he's a colleague, would you mind helping him?