# Making worker a static parameter libpqxx

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpq, libpqxx

I'm trying to create a class that is tasked with creating the link between Postgres and c++. I'm trying to make the worker a static item so that I can use it in any function without modifying it so I don't have to keep instantiating it, but I don't know how to declare it as I keep getting errors

[image: this is how I tried declaring it and the error I get]

I would appreciate if you guys could help me find a way to properly declare the worker

The code in the picture:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

class DBLink
{
public:
    DBLink();
    static pqxx::work worker = worker(connectionObject);
private:
    std::string connectionString = "host=ec2-54-74-35-87.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=d8iolcesns1bj4 user=pktunepcutgdqh password=7e3eeef2e01e0d8ae555c7236b1c3375789259dfb6acba41225cc4f55394836c";
    pqxx::connection connectionObject;

    virtual void function() = 0;
};
```

Comment: I wanted to help you, but I couldn't copy the text from the picture.

Comment: one moment, i'll put the code under the picture

Comment: Do you study in the same class with one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69874768/using-libpqxx-and-c-how-to-instantiate-a-connectionobject-and-an-worker-in-a)

Comment: yes, we have an assignment regarding databases and using them in c++